# Python. Strange class attributes behavior

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
>>> class Abcd:

...     a = ''
...     menu = ['a', 'b', 'c']
... 
>>> a = Abcd()
>>> b = Abcd()
>>> a.a = 'a'
>>> b.a = 'b'
>>> a.a
'a'
>>> b.a
'b'
```

It's all correct and each object has own 'a', but...

```
>>> a.menu.pop()
'c'
>>> a.menu
['a', 'b']
>>> b.menu
['a', 'b']
```

How could this happen?
And how to use list as class attribute?

Comment: You're definitely not the first to run into this. I remember hitting this issue for the first time: it took me days to figure out what the problem was. It makes sense once you learn it, but I personally think it's really unintuitive.

Comment: @musicfreak: I really don't get why people are confused by this. By looking at any OO example in any tutorial you will learn this. Why anyone would prefer to waste "days" instead of investing a few hours to read a tutorial is beyond me.

Comment: -1: There are tons of duplicates for this.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a class attribute, but rather an instance attribute. How to do this is covered in the official tutorial http://docs.python.org/tut/ and in books like http://tinyurl.com/thinkcspy2e

Comment: I came from php and java, for me this conceptions (as "and or" feature and private/protected policy) are strange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the way you're initializing the `menu` property is setting all of the instances to point to the same list, as opposed to different lists with the same value.

Instead, use the `__init__` member function of the class to initialize values, thus creating a new list and assigning that list to the property for that particular instance of the class:

```
class Abcd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ''
        self.menu = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: But, that about different between simple string attribute and list attribute?
Why?

Comment: Because it's the difference between a reference and a value. If you did `a.menu = ['a','b']`, then `b.menu` would be left unchanged - but you're not, you're changing the list *pointed to* by `a.menu`.

Answer (score 4):

See [class-objects](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) in the tutorial, and notice the use of `self`.

Use instance attributes, not class attributes (and also, new style classes) :

```
>>> class Abcd(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = ''
...         self.menu = ['a','b','c']
...         
>>> a=Abcd()
>>> b=Abcd()
>>> a.a='a'
>>> b.a='b'
>>> a.a
'a'
>>> b.a
'b'
>>> a.menu.pop()
'c'
>>> a.menu
['a', 'b']
>>> b.menu
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```

Comment: You might want to note that all classes are automatically new-style classes in the Python 3.0+ line.

Answer (score 0):

because variables in Python are just "labels"

both Abcd.menu and a.menu reference the same list object.

in your case you should assign the label to a new object,

not modify the object inplace.

You can run

```
a.menu = a.menu[:-1]
```

instead of

```
a.menu.pop()
```

to feel the difference