# How can self denote Class1 and this at the same time?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class Class1():
  var1 = "var1"
  VAR2 = "VAR2"

  def __init__(self):
    self.var3 = "var3"

  def method1(self):
    print "var1 is: " + self.var1 # or Class1.var1, self denotes Class1
    print "var2 is: " + self.VAR2 # or Class1.VAR2, self denotes Class1
    print "var3 is: " + self.var3 # self denotes an instance of Class1


c = Class1()
c.method1()
```

I am looking at this and I'm wondering: why does `self` in `method1()` refer to `this` (instance) and `Class1` (class itself) at the same time? And should I use `self` or `Class1` for `var1` and `VAR2`?

And should I name "static" constants "var1" (small letter) or "VAR2" (BIG LETTERS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look up an attribute on an instance of a class, Python first tries to find it on that instance.  If it's not there, it looks on the class.  (And if it's not there, it looks in the superclasses, all the way up the inheritance chain.)  `self` refers only to the instance, but the process of finding an attribute involves looking at the class (and superclasses) if necessary.  This is described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) (see the sections on "Classes" and "Class instances").

In your example, `self.var3` finds the attribute on the instance.  `self.var1` and `self.var2` find it on the class.

You can find many questions on StackOverflow arising from people trying to figure out the nuances of this in various situations.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317366/peculiar-behavior-of-classes-in-python) is one example.

As for how to name them, the standard convention is to use lowercase.  However, if you intend for them to be constant-like values, uppercase can be okay.  In either case, you should familiarize yourself with how class attributes actually work, so that you aren't surprised later when you try to do something with them.

Comment: what if I had a class and instance variables with the same name?

Comment: @Grienders: Then the instance one will shadow the class one so that `self.blah` deals with the instance one, because, as I said, the lookup starts with the instance, and only goes to the class if the attribute isn't on the instance.  See the question I linked to for some more examples of how this works.

Answer (score 1):

All instances share class level attributes; so when you are doing `self.var1`, since there is no `var1` at the instance level, it goes up the resolution order and finds it at the class.

To access class level variables *outside of an instance*, you can use the "direct" path to it, `Class1.var1`.

As for your other question - Python doesn't have "static" constants (or constants at all). For naming guidance refer to the [python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which states the following:

> Method Names and Instance Variables
>
> Use the function naming rules:
> lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve
> readability.
>
> Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance
> variables.
>
> To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to
> invoke Python's name mangling rules.
>
> Python mangles these names with the class name: if class Foo has an
> attribute named __a, it cannot be accessed by Foo.__a. (An insistent
> user could still gain access by calling Foo._Foo__a.) Generally,
> double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts
> with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed.